# Is it possible to backup stored routines and functions with Innobackupex?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, backup, percona-tools, xtrabackup

I am running a few restore tests on my Dev and I've noticed that the stored routines are not being restored with the innobackupx. Is that something achievable ? Am I doing something wrong ?

I am only using innodb tables so it will be good to restore the db using only innobackupx.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to take the backup of MySQL Server Objects i.e `routines / triggers / events` you can do like below

```
mysqldump -h$MySQLHost -u$YourUser -p$YourPassword --no-data --no-create-info --routines --triggers --events $Database > MySQLStoredProcedures.sql
```

The above will backup only the database objects , no data , no create table etc.

Comment: So I guess I have to rely on mysqldump to do that is not possible to do in one go from innobackupx. Thanks for your reply @Abdul Manaf

Comment: I hope you have not taken the backup of `MySQL database`, the way I have suggested you can take the backup of the only database objects (SP/Functions/Triggers) and restore it to your Dev server, This will also not cause conflicts to your existing dev server.

Comment: Irrelevant answer. Innobackupex is a percona product and can do what the person asks.

Answer (score 5):

Stored procedures are stored in database `mysql`. `Innobackupex` copies it by default. Make sure database `mysql` is restored with other databases.